# Apply array_values to every array field inside an object

Tags: php, arrays, class

I have a PHP stdClass Object. Inside it can be many fields and some of them are arrays. Also a field can be an Object that can contain fields with arrays on it.

The idea is to iterate through the object and perform the array_values operation when an array is found.

A possible object could be as follows for example:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
["name"]=>
string(14) "I am an object"
["object"]=>
object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
  ["0"]=>
  string(6) "item 1"
  ["1"]=>
  string(6) "item 2"
  ["2"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "3.1"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "3.2"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "3.3"
  }
}
["list"]=>
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "item 1"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "item 2"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "item 3"
}
}
```

Any ideas on how to iterate recursively through the object and apply array_values to every array?

Comment: so you basically want array_values to return **ALL** of the values in the entire array, no matter how deeply they're buried?

Comment: more importantly, are you not trying to preserve your key values?

Comment: @MarcB I want a function that return the same object (after having applied array_values to all arrays inside it).

Comment: @VikingBlooded I don´t want to preserve the key values. The idea of applying array_values is just to ¨reorder¨ the key values. So if I have the keys [0][2][5][9] I want to transform it into an array with keys [0][1][2][3]

Comment: well, you could just loop through each array iteration and write them to a var[] array and be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally used this function. It does just what I wanted.

```
function rec_array_values(&$item){
    if(is_object($item)){
        foreach ($item as $key => &$value) {
            $key = rec_array_values($value);
        }
    }else if(is_array($item)){
        foreach ($item as $key => &$value) {
            $key = rec_array_values($value);
        }
        $item = array_values($item);
    }
}
```